# How to force the request to fail in ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a class that inherit `ActionFilterAttribute`.

It decrypt some query string Attributes that comes in the Request encrypted by the caller. This ensures my WebAPI methods receive only "good" parameters. And that is working good.

What I need to do and had no success is to negate/fail the context (request) if a parameter is not encrypted.

How to force the request to terminate?
I´am doing my logic at:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
```

Already tried to set the response to 401, but that doesn´t work:

```
//Negate the access by default
 context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. As Clint B said, one of the approaches is using Middleware. 
   [Here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/middleware.html) is an ASP Core documentation about Middleware with how-to examples
2. On the other hand, if you use MVC and want to use ActionFilter to force MVC Action to stop, you can do this by setting Action Context `.Result` property to a non-null value.

Example:

```
actionContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
actionContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Clear();

actionContext.Result = new EmptyResult();
//var wrongResult = new { error = "Wrong parameters"};
//actionContext.Result = new JsonResult(wrongResult);
```

> How to chose  between Middleware and Action filter? Action filter can be used as a method filter, controller filter, or global filter **only for MVC** HTTP requests.
>
> Middleware is component that "sits" on the HTTP pipeline and examines **all requests and responses**.

3. For Request parameters validation you may use [Data Annotations](https://damienbod.com/2015/10/24/using-dataannotations-and-localization-in-asp-net-5-mvc-6/).

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this in ASP.NET Core is to write custom middleware.  Just setting the response status code during the request will have no effect. Because when the request reaches the middleware that generates the response, the status code will be overwritten.

If you did this in middleware, you could stop the request right there and send back a 401 response.

EDIT:
I posted a tutorial project on GitHub that demonstrates how to create custom middleware with dependency injection in three easy steps.  I haven't converted it to RC2 yet but you don't have to run it to learn how to do it.  It's very simple.  Read the ReadMe file and it explains how to search the code for the relevant areas. You can download the project [here](https://github.com/ClintBailiff/MiddlewareDemo).

Comment: hmm. Any tips of how to implement that custom middleware? Must inheriet another interface and it on DI at startup?

Comment: Read the docs, they are well explained and detailed on that topic https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/middleware.html ...